# How do I enable access-period on freeradius 3.0 for daloradius

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, freeradius

I am trying to enable access-period on free radius 3.0,

I have added access-period module and authorize.

```
sqlcounter accessperiod {
           counter-name = Max-Access-Period-Time
           check-name = Access-Period
           sqlmod-inst = sql
           key = User-Name
           reset = never
           query = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(AcctStartTime) FROM radacct \
           WHERE UserName = '%{%k}' LIMIT 1"
   }
```

In the authorization part:

```
accessperiod
}

 Loaded module rlm_sqlcounter
  # Loading module "accessperiod" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/acessperiod

  sqlcounter accessperiod {
/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/acessperiod[1]: Configuration item "sql_module_instance" must have a value
/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/acessperiod[1]: Invalid configuration for module "accessperiod"
```

Comment: I am seeing the same issue on Debian 9.5 running on BeagleBone Black.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.
Check freeradius 3 sqlcounter format. Then adjust sqlcounter from contrib directory to work with radius3. The counter format in contrib is for freeradius2

Other option: try to downgrade to freeradius 2 if you are able to do that.